# Не подключается функция: Call to a member function on nul

Tags: php

В Opencart создал страницу для вывода некоторых функций. Файлы с вызываемыми функциями в той же директории. Но происходит ошибка `Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on null` . К базе данных подключение есть.

```
class Controllermailtest extends Controller{

    public function index(){

        $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder(32);
    }
}
```

Comment: По всей вероятности вы не подключили класс model к данному файлу, найдите в какой модели есть метод getOrder() её и подключите к новому файлу

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас родительский класс определяет свойство `$this->model_checkout_order` ?

Comment: @teran, да, так вызывается модель в опенкарте.

Comment: @Arsen, в файле из той же директории, в классе `ControllerMailOrder extends Controller` в которой вызывается та же модель, нет явного подключения к файлу, если только нет автозагрузки где-нибудь.

Comment: @Arsen, и в самом деле, надо было подключить модель `$this->load->model('checkout/order');`

Comment: @mehanizator вот вот :)  Как говорится, истина всегда рядом :)